# How to get text from Search Suggestion onClick

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-searchmanager, android-search

I just implemented search with custom suggestion and I am still wondering, how to get the text of the clicked suggestion in another `Activity`. I cant do that with `intent.getData().getLastPathSegment()` because i am passing another text with this method. But is there any different solution, how to get the text?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 ?

Comment: yes, exactly, but how do i cet it to string?

Comment: cursor.getString(columnIdx)

Comment: cursor.getString(SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1) it has to look like this?

Comment: no, SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 is a column name, you need its idx, see Cursor docs how. to get index from name